# Share via my App

Tags: android, android-intent

I am working on making an app which is a status sharing app, users share images and text messages through my app,  now I want it to appear in the list when sharing images or text from facebook or google+ [image]

Comment: you should google `IntentFilter` in AndroidManifest file.

Comment: Add an [intent filter](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html)

Comment: Can you please show me how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your Manifest file

> ```
>     <activity
>     android:name="Activity"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="test">
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>     </intent-filter>
>
>    <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
>
>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>
>         <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
>     </intent-filter>
>
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
>
>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>
>         <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
>     </intent-filter>
>
>     <intent-filter>
>         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
>
>         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>
>         <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
>     </intent-filter>
> </activity>
> ```

Comment: And changes in  java?